# Intersection of affine hyperplanes

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, affine-geometry

In [dimension of intersection of hyperplanes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322425/dimension-of-intersection-of-hyperplanes/2742832) in the answer it is explained that the intersection of a affine hyperplane and $m$-dimensional affine subspace can have 3 scenarios.

The first two are pretty much logical and easy to understand, but why is the proper intersection exactly of dimension $m-1$ (one less than the $m$-dimensional affine subspace)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a good notion of hyperplane I restrict myself to a $d$-dimensional vector space with $d<\infty$.

Suppose we have an affine hyperplane $H$ and another affine subspace $A$ of dimension $m$.

If $m=d$ we have $A=V$ so $\dim A\cap H = \dim H = d-1 =m-1$.

If $A$ is contained in $H$ then $\dim A \cap H = \dim A = m$.

If $A$ is parallel to a subspace of $H$ and they don’t share a common point, then $A\cap H=\emptyset$ and the dimension of the intersection is not defined.

Otherwise they do intersect and it suffices to restrict to the case that both $A$ and $H$ are linear subspaces (not affine anymore). We find $A+H=V$, since otherwise $A$ would be contained in $H$. Hence the dimension formula yields
$$\begin{align*}
d &= \dim V\\
&= \dim (A + H)\\
&= \dim A + \dim H - \dim (A\cap H)\\
&= d-1 + m - \dim A\cap H
\end{align*}$$
Thus we get $\dim (A \cap H) = m-1$.

Comment: Thank you..makes a lot of sense now :)

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: As for why it "suffices to restrict... (not affine anymore)", we can refer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051366/linear-algebra-intersection-of-affine-spaces) to see that for two affine spaces that intersect, their intersection is an affine space parallel to the intersection of the two subspaces.